# A friend's sketchbook

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual

I was going through some old sketchbooks with a friend when I found this page:
[image]

I'm not sure what it could mean, but I seem to recall that this friend of mine loved making puzzles.

Hint:

> One last **comment**: this friend **historically** used vigenere variants in his puzzles.

Hint 2:

> Despite the previous hint, the [knowledge](/questions/tagged/knowledge) tag is not needed for this puzzle.

Hint 3:

> Daniel S was on the right track, but a couple of pieces of text need to be extracted from the image ([steganography](/questions/tagged/steganography) is not required)

Answer (score 6):

It might be

> SACRED COWS

The images all appear to be

> figures of speech with the correct animal appearing in the next picture.

Thus

> I. Raining cats and dogs
>  II-III. Hold you horses
>  IV. Cat got your tongue
>  V. Dance monkey
>  VI. Bird brained
>  VII. Make a beeline for the exit
>  VIII. Ants in your pants
>  IX. Straw that broke the camel’s back
>  X. Butterflies in the stomach
>  XI. Sacred cows (assuming wrap around)

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not the solution. You're on the right track, but there's much more to it than just that.

Comment: I think VI is probably rot13(gjb oveqf jvgu bar fgbar).  And I think XI is likely rot13(ubyl pbj).

Answer (score 2):

As noted by Daniel S:

> The images all appear to be
>
> > figures of speech with the correct animal appearing in the next picture.

Going off of the answer, we have (for a partial answer):

> I. Raining cats and dogs. (animals falling from the sky, used to represent when it is raining really hard)

> II-III. Hold your horses. (stop what you're doing. There might be another animal idiom involving horses that would relate to this, but I can't think of it.)

> IV. Cat got your tongue (unable to talk due to nervousness)

> V. Dance monkey (acting foolishly for the entertainment of others)

> VI. Killing two birds with one stone (getting 2 things done at once)

> VII. Make a beeline for the exit (go to the exit)

> VIII. Ants in your pants (acting very jittery?)

> IX. Straw that broke the camel's back (Wasting a last chance to do something)

> X. Butterflies in the stomach (being homesick?)

> XI. Holy cow (very impressive)

So it might be

> Holy cow (since it would be very impressive if someone solved it correctly)

---

<sub>*This answer is based off of Daniel S' answer and 0x5453's comment*</sub>

Comment: IMO I do not think it is correct BTW.

Comment: You're on the right track, but there's more that needs to be done before the solution can be found. Maybe take a look at the hints.