# A simple and quite fun cipher puzzle

Tags: cipher

<sub>*Don't worry, this is my creation :)*</sub>

---

Goal of this puzzle: Decrypt the puzzle to find out what the secret (final) message is. Each part of the puzzle depends on the previous part (except for the first).

Part 1:

> 25 15 21 13 9 7 8 20 23 1 14 20 20 15 11 14 15 23 20 8 1 20 20 8 9 19 9 19 16 18 15 2 1 2 12 25 7 15 9 14 7 20 15 2 5 20 8 5 5 1 19 9 5 19 20 16 1 18 20 15 6 20 8 5 16 21 26 26 12 5 6 15 18 20 8 5 14 5 24 20 16 1 18 20 15 6 20 8 5 16 21 26 26 12 5 25 15 21 13 9 7 8 20 23 1 14 20 20 15 21 19 5 18 15 20 20 8 9 18 20 5 5 14 1 12 19 15 21 19 9 14 7 1 19 15 6 20 23 1 18 5 12 9 11 5 3 18 25 16 20 9 9 13 9 7 8 20 8 5 12 16

Part 2:

> **Jbjmref**, gung'f vzcerffvir. Rvgure guvf vf gur erny rnfvrfg cneg bs gur chmmyr (sbe boivbhf ernfbaf) be gur svefg cneg bs gur chmmyr vf gur rnfvrfg. Nyfb, n uvag: Pelcgbpheerapvrf unir abguvat gb qb jvgu gur svany nafjre. Nyfb, vs lbh ertneqrq gur ynfg uvag (nygubhtu vg'f abg erdhverq gb), lbh cebonoyl xabj jung gb qb sebz urer.

Part 3:

> Lnl, gur frpbaq gb ynfg cneg! V xabj lbh pna qb guvf! Juvyr guvf jbhyq fgvyy or pbafvqrerq na rnfl cneg. (hfvat oehgr sbepr zvtug uryc, ohg gung'f fgvyy fybjre) Uvag: Lbh xabj, V'ir arire zragvbarq vg, ohg V qb yvxr navznyf, rfcrpvnyyl snez navznyf. Vg'f abg yvxr na bofrffvba jvgu gurz, zber yvxr V yvxr **navzny vqvbzf**. V nyfb erzbirq ahzoref sebz guvf cneg gb znxr fher oehgr sbepr vf zber qvssvphyg. Tb qbja bapr zber gb or noyr gb qrpbqr gur svany cneg bs gur chmmyr.

Part 4:

> ~?6 =2DE A2CEP x7 J@F >2<6 :E E9:D 72C[ x H@F=5 =:<6 E@ @?6[ D2J E92E **E92EVD :>AC6DD:G6** 249:6G6>6?E @7 DE:4<:?8 H:E9 E9:D AFKK=6[ 2?5 EH@[ 2A@=@8:K6 7@C DF49 325 AFKK=6 56D:8?] x 9@?6DE=J 766= =:<6 x 4@F=5 92G6 W:? 2== H2JDX 56D:8?65 E9:D E@ 36 >@C6 Q7F?4E:@?2=Q[ :7 J@F 42E49 >J 5C:7E] qFE @E96CH:D6[ E92?<D[ 2?5 J@F D9@F=5 92G6 2== @7 E96 :?7@ ?66565 E@ AFE E@86E96C E96 7:?2= >6DD286]

---

### Hints

---

Hint 1:

> Maybe the bolded words mean something? (not including Hint 4, although that still matters)

Hint 2:

> Don't worry, Part 1 and Part 4 aren't as intimidating as they seem!

Hint 3:

> Notice that I did not put the [no-computers](/questions/tagged/no-computers) tag. While the first three parts can be decoded without electronics, the fourth part is probably impossible to decode without a computer.

Hint 4:

> The answer will be structured as `(WORD 1) (WORD 2), (WORD 3) (WORD 4)!`. Capitalization **does not matter**

Hint 5

> Note the [logical-deduction](/questions/tagged/logical-deduction) tag. This does not mean that the entire thing can be deduced on its own (as noted by Hint 3), it just is there to note that the final answer can be logically deduced on its own.

---

A perfect answer would include:

> What each part is (in decrypted form)
>
> What is bolded in the parts that have bolded words. (aside from the decryption itself)
>
> What was used to decrypt each part.
>
> The final answer.

Comment: Note that Part 4 has an accidental typo (and sorry for not noticing this until now) but otherwise everything makes perfect sense.

Comment: Not a downvoter, but I suspect that it has something to do with some of the feedback given by BeastlyGerbil below.  It's great for a first puzzle, but there are ways that it could be improved, and like BG mentioned, these are pretty simple ciphers to crack, especially for seasoned puzzlers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Part 1:

> Simple A1Z26:
>
> 'YOU MIGHT WANT TO KNOW THAT THIS IS PROBABLY GOING TO BE THE EASIEST PART OF THE PUZZLE FOR THE NEXT PART OF THE PUZZLE YOU MIGHT WANT TO USE ROT THIRTEEN ALSO USING A SOFTWARE LIKE CRYPTII MIGHT HELP'

Part 2:

> Using rot13 as mentioned:
>
> '**Wowzers**, that's impressive. Either this is the real easiest part of the puzzle (for obvious reasons) or the first part of the puzzle is the easiest. Also, a hint: Cryptocurrencies have nothing to do with the final answer. Also, if you regarded the last hint (although it's not required to), you probably know what to do from here.'

Part 3:

> Rot 13 once again:
>
> 'Yay, the second to last part! I know you can do this! While this would still be considered an easy part. (using brute force might help, but that's still slower) Hint: You know, I've never mentioned it, but I do like animals, especially farm animals. It's not like an obsession with them, more like I like **animal idioms**. I also removed numbers from this part to make sure brute force is more difficult. Go down once more to be able to decode the final part of the puzzle.'

Part 4:

> This is a Rot-47 cipher. I am not sure if this is hinted at somehow, but easily identifiable with the right tools
>
> 'One last part! If you make it this far, I would like to one, say that that's **impressive achievement** of sticking with this puzzle, and two, apologize for such bad puzzle design. I honestly feel like I could have (in all ways) designed this to be more "functional", if you catch my drift. But otherwise, thanks, and you should have all of the info needed to put together the final message.'

---

Final answer:

> <sub>Update: This puzzle was improved and remade such that the answer could be properly found, and that answer can be found [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/125979/18250) if you are interested</sub>
>
>
>  I am honestly not sure on what the final answer is here. We know it is 4 words from the hint, and we have the words in bold 'Wowzers', 'Animal Idioms', and 'Impressive achievement', but I haven't found any obvious sort of answer that would fit these.
>
> I shall keep looking, but my guess right now would be 'Something to crow about', however this doesn't have a comma after the second word
>
> Confirmed the first part is 'Holy cow', ... not sure about the second half

---

Feedback:

> Thought I'd give some feedback as it's a first puzzle, and while honestly by no means is it a bad start (hell it's much better than my first puzzle), there are definitely some improvements that can be made for future puzzles:
>
> Firstly some useful links for cipher puzzles in general, both [What not to do](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1717/code-puzzles-what-not-to-do), (small self-plug) [a guide to cipher types](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/52118/guide-to-codes-and-ciphers) and also just [looking through the top cipher puzzles on the site](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cipher?tab=Votes) to get an idea of what does well.
>
> For this puzzle in particular, it is slightly disjointed as in any of the 4 parts can be cracked without the previous one through some basic cryptanalysis. It could have been better for instance if decoding the first part gave the key for the second part or similar
>
> The answer also seems to be a bit of a guess through same vague hints in the question. There are a lot of possibilities and no real way to know which is correct. The 4 parts don't really give any information on what the answer is- so they also seem a bit pointless
>
> Finally, for hints on the site, it is usual practice to not give any hints to start, and then after a couple of days if no progress is being made, give a hint. If you think your puzzle needs a bunch of hints to start with to be able to be solved, it might be too hard or the hint could be woven into the question itself another way
>
> Hope this helps! Looking forward to more puzzles in the future, and hopefully this feedback can give a bit of a guide for the next.

Comment: Luckily, you are on the right track, but no, sadly, the final answer is incorrect. Apart from that, though, everything is exactly correct. :)

Comment: You beat me to it. My brain was thinking the answer is "rot13: ubyl pbj".

Comment: @poco You have the first two words down of the final answer, now just to think what the other two might be :)

Comment: @CrSb0001 are there any hints in the decrypted parts other than the bold bits, or is it pure guesswork from here?

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil Yeah, I guess it is pretty much pure guesswork. I think what I was trying to do was have the solver notice that "wowzers" and "animal idioms" had some significance. But other than that, yeah, sorry about that.

Comment: @CrSb0001 included a bit of feedback for you as I'm off to bed, hopefully it can be of help to you, please don't take it in a bad way or anything, just trying to give some help for next time :)

Comment: By the way, did you inspire the solving process from [this other question?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/122602/a-friends-sketchbook)

Comment: @poco The solving process I guess was half-inspired from the question (the animal idiom part), although it could be argued that the entire solving process was based on it. So in other words, yes. Sorry if it caused any confusion.

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil Also thanks for the feedback. I will most definitely keep those pointers in mind.

Comment: @CrSb0001 if you're willing, could you give the second half of the answer / a big hint for the answer just so this gets all wrapped up? Feel like it's worth finishing it off (you can even create a mini puzzle in a comment with your new skills if you want, just anything which could confirm the right answer rather than just guessing)

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil I'll definitely include it in a mini puzzle :) Give me 15 hours - I think that'll be enough time to do so.