# My smol boi puzzle! :3

Tags: cipher

<sub>*It should be noted that all this puzzle intends to do is give the second half of the answer to my [first](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/122668/86115) puzzle, while being a puzzle itself. Other than that, this is just your normal smol boi puzzle :3*</sub>

---

Time for a smol boi puzzle! The rules are simple: Find the hidden message in the smol boi puzzle. That's literally it.

---

Part 1

> --- .... / -. --- . ... -.-.-- / -.-- --- ..- / .... .- ... / -.. . -.-. --- -.. . -.. / -- -.-- / -- . ... ... .- --. . .-.-.- / --. .- ... .--. -.-.-- / ---... --- / -.-- --- ..- / .-- .- -. - / .- / .... .. -. - ..--.. ..--.. ..--.. ..--.. ..--.. / -. .- .... .... / .. / -.. --- / .-.. .. -.- . / ...- .. --. . -. . .-. . / -.-. .. .--. .... . .-. ... / - .... --- / ---... ...-- / --- .... / -. --- . ... -.-.-- / .. / --. .- ...- . / - .... . / -.- . -.-- / .- .-- .- -.-- / ---... ---

Part 2

> ea k e 5l ej dg 5t m k dn 5j i 8f e7 q ec h eh

---

#### Notes

<sub>Look at my smol boi puzzle :3</sub>

---

This is not wowzers :(

---

Hint 1

> [Someone](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/69302/someone) already found the key. Twice

Comment: rot13(BU ABRF! LBH UNF QRPBQRQ ZL ZRFFNTR. TNFC! :B LBH JNAG N UVAG????? ANUU V QB YVXR IVTRARER PVCUREF GUB :3 BU ABRF! V TNIR GUR XRL NJNL :B) well…time to find the key.

Comment: Vigenere? How intere... NO!!!!